# Could not find or load main class - Spring, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have class where I have static main method to run application spring application in eclipse. When i run her i get "Error: Could not find or load main class", if I run simple project without spring, then it works correct. I also run by configurations, but still doesn't work. I try to resolve second day !!!

My RunApplication class:

```
package com.butlerApp.MyButler.runner;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;


public class RunApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(RunApplication.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

My error:Error: Could not find or load main class com.butlerApp.MyButler.runner.RunApplication

Please for help

Comment: please include the neccessary code as text in your question and not as a link

Comment: Are you using package credential in proper manner to execute and run the program,because you have defined package. ?

Comment: I don't know what is "package credential"

Comment: I add  @SpringBootApplication, but still doesn't works

Comment: Please see the Error section of eclipse .You probably have some error in compilation or any build path issues because of which class file is not getting generated and eclipse is unable to find the main class file.

Comment: I have this error in log: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core".                                                                                           java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.internal.validation.SpringDataValidator$SpringValidationElementLifecycleManager.destory()V